# Avira reports a hidden driver or memory modification, how can I find location

Tags: windows, anti-virus

My problem is the following:

On Windows 7 I did a scan using Avira and it says:
Hidden driver
  [NOTE]      A memory modification has been detected, which could potentially be used to hide file access attempts.

I am aware this might not be a real problem, still I want to find out the location of this memory modification.

I ran the scan with reporting set on complete, still I do not get any more information, even though the log file I get has a size of around 500M.

I tried to find out using the avira manual and did a search on the avira web site, it said that if I ran the scan with reporting on complete, the log file would contain information about the location, just in my case it does not.

Is there a way within Avira to find out about the location of this memory modification? Is it possible that Avira finds a memory modification, without being able to relate it to a registry entry, a file name, a process or sth else? 
If this is the case, what can I do to find out more?

Thanks in advance.